# Django: Is there a way to effienctly bulk get_or_create()

Tags: json, django, database, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I need to import a database (given in JSON format) of papers and authors.
The database is very large (194 million entries) so I am forced to use django's bulk_create() method.

To load the authors for the first time I use the following script:

```
def load_authors(paper_json_entries: List[Dict[str, any]]):
    authors: List[Author] = []
    for paper_json in paper_json_entries:
        for author_json in paper_json['authors']:
            # len != 0 is needed as a few authors dont have a id
            if len(author_json['ids']) and not Author.objects.filter(author_id=author_json['ids'][0]).exists():
                authors.append(Author(author_id=author_json['ids'][0], name=author_json['name']))
    Author.objects.bulk_create(set(authors))
```

However, this is much too slow.
The bottleneck is this query:

`and not Author.objects.filter(author_id=author_json['ids'][0]).exists():`

Unfortunately I have to make this query, because of course one author can write multiple papers and otherwise there will be a key conflict.

Is there a way to implement something like the normal `get_or_create()` efficiently with bulk_create?

Comment: "ignore_conflicts=True" would do in db side another thing you should consider for 200M entries is using some kind of Generator functionality instead of List. for example "open()" gives you an file object that yields a line each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid creating entries with existing unique keys, you can enable the `ignore_conflicts` parameter:

```
def load_authors(paper_json_entries: List[Dict[str, any]]):
    Author.objects.bulk_create(
        (
            Author(author_id=author_json['ids'][0], name=author_json['name'])
            for paper_json in paper_json_entries
            for author_json in paper_json['authors']
        ),
        ignore_conflicts=True
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what i was looking for!